# Why might the AWS JavaScript SDK StartAssetBundleExportJobCommand fail as not being a constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-quicksight

I have the following Lambda code to start a QuickSight asset export but I am experiencing the following error error when it runs.

`import_client_quicksight.StartAssetBundleExportJobCommand is not a constructor`

I must have a bug is something that I am doing but I can't figure out how I got this wrong. Any thoughts?

```
import { QuickSightClient, StartAssetBundleExportJobCommand, StartAssetBundleExportJobCommandInput } from "@aws-sdk/client-quicksight";
import { Guid } from "guid-typescript";

const ACCOUNT_ID = process.env['ACCOUNT_ID'];
const REGION_ID = process.env['REGION_ID'];

const quicksightClient = new QuickSightClient({ region: REGION_ID });

export const handler = async (event: any): Promise<any> => {
    console.log('event', event);

    if (!event.DashboardsArns) {
        throw new Error('No DashboardsArns provided');
    }

    const startExportCommandInput: StartAssetBundleExportJobCommandInput = {
        AwsAccountId: ACCOUNT_ID,
        AssetBundleExportJobId: Guid.create().toString(),
        ResourceArns: event.DashboardsArns as string[],
        IncludeAllDependencies: true,
        ExportFormat: 'CLOUDFORMATION_JSON',
    };

    const startExportCommand = new StartAssetBundleExportJobCommand(startExportCommandInput);

    const start_asset_export_job_result = await quicksightClient.send(startExportCommand);

    if (!start_asset_export_job_result) 
      throw new Error('Empty result from StartAssetBundleExportJobCommand');

    if (start_asset_export_job_result.Status !== 200)
      throw new Error(`StartAssetBundleExportJobCommand failed with status ${start_asset_export_job_result.Status}`);

    if (!start_asset_export_job_result.AssetBundleExportJobId) {
        throw new Error('No AssetBundleExportJobId returned');
    }

    return {
      AssetBundleExportJobId: start_asset_export_job_result.AssetBundleExportJobId
    };
};
```

Comment: I think the bundler is doing something wrong. Are you using esbuild?

Comment: It looks like the SDK in the Lambda runtime didn't have the latest.